# Directx 11 Registers

Tags: c++, memory, directx, textures, directx-11

I'm somewhat confused about registers in DirectX 11. Let me give an example of the situation: Assume you have 3 models. They each have a texture that is mapped to register t0. Models 1 and 3 use the same texture, and model 2 uses a different texture. When drawing model 1, I set the texture resource view to register 0 and draw the model. Then I do the same things for models 2 and 3, but use the same resource view for model 3. When I set the the texture for model 2, does the GPU replace the texture in the GPU memory with a different one, or does it maintain that texture memory until space is needed and just moves some pointers around? I would like to minimize data transfer to GPU and I'm wondering if I should handle situations like these myself or does DX handle it for me. Btw, I am NOT using the Effects 11 framework.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you should assume that once you have created a resource on the GPU (e.g. using `CreateTexture2D`), that memory is reserved and resident for that resource for use by the 3D pipeline.  Note that this is **independent** of data *transfer* to the GPU, which is also explicit via `Map`/`Unmap` or `UpdateSubresource`.

There are some cases where the OS will swap memory in and out, but usually this should be avoided if possible.  For example, if you create a bunch of large textures but never access them, eventually the video memory manager will page them out to system memory for other tasks (e.g. watching Netflix / browsing the internet on another display).  You can also run into real problems if you overcommit video memory (using more than what is available on the system).  This used to be impossible (you would just get `E_OUTOFMEMORY`) but now the memory manager tries to make it work by paging things to system memory or even disk.  This is something you should *really* strive to avoid since if you ever bind and use a paged-out resource, you'll get a glitch waiting for the memory manager to page it back in for use.

Note that the above really just applies to discrete GPU configs.  On integrated systems e.g. from Intel or AMD, you get unified memory which has completely different characteristics.  But in general you should target discrete configs first, since there are more performance cliffs you have to worry about if you screwed something up, and they would be unlikely to show up on integrated.

Going back to your original question, changing SRVs between draw calls is not that expensive - it's more than a pointer swap, but nowhere near the cost of transferring the entire texture across the bus.  You should feel free to swap SRVs at the same frequency as your draw calls and expect no adverse performance impact.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're asking depends a lot on hardware and driver implementation. That's also why DX11 documentation doesn't do any claims on how memory is managed for graphics resources. I can't really give you any valid sources but I believe it's safe to assume that textures/buffers for which you've made a view will reside in GPU's memory (especially the ones you're accessing more frequently). The graphics driver will do a lot of access optimization. However, it's good practice to change the state of graphics pipeline as little as possible.

You can read an in depth discussion of graphics pipeline [here](http://fgiesen.wordpress.com/2011/07/09/a-trip-through-the-graphics-pipeline-2011-index/)